# error compiling css assets with compass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass, sass

hi i am trying to convert the following following with compass, though i am getting a compile error stating 'Undefined mixin background-image'

```
#header_toolbar {
height: 40px;
/* The black toolbar gradient :) */
background: #313131; /* Old browsers */
@include background-image(linear-gradient(left top, #313131, #101010));
/*background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #313131 0%, #101010 100%); *//* FF3.6+ *//*
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#313131), color-stop(100%,#101010)); *//* Chrome,Safari4+ *//*
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #313131 0%,#101010 100%); *//* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ *//*
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #313131 0%,#101010 100%); *//* Opera 11.10+ *//*
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #313131 0%,#101010 100%); *//* IE10+ *//*
background: linear-gradient(top,  #313131 0%,#101010 100%); *//* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#313131', endColorstr='#101010',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

}

gemfile

```
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem "compass", "~> 0.12.1"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the mixin in your scss:

```
 @import "compass/css3/images"
```

http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/

Take a look here for an idea about getting your imports in one place rather than defining them in every scss file: http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/best_practices/

Comment: am i missing something here, but when i added that line i get `found to import not found or readable`

Comment: What do you have in your Gemfile? Are you using the compass-rails gem rather than the compass gem?

Comment: try moving compass and compass-rails outside of the assets group